# enumerate multiple copies of jQuery loaded into a page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, widget

I need to embed a pice of JavaScript code  into a 3rd party web site. The web site has multiple copies  of jQuery loaded statically and possibly dynamically. There is also a  copy of jQuery UI loaded at some moment into the web site and only one of jQueries gets extended with the ui namespace. My code depends on both jQuery and jQuery UI and thus I need to locate the copy of jQuery with the ui namespace in it.

Is there a way to enumerate all jQueries loaded into a page and locate the one which has the ui namespace in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enumerate all copies of jQuery loaded into a page using jQuery.noConflict:

```
function unwindJquery(jQuery) {
    var res = [];
    if (jQuery&&jQuery.fn&&jQuery.fn.jquery) {
        res.push(jQuery);
        var jQueryOriginal = window.jQuery;
        try {
            jQuery.noConflict(true);//fill window.jQuery with previous copy
            if (window.jQuery&&window.jQuery!=jQueryOriginal) {
                res = res.concat(unwindJquery(window.jQuery));
            }
        } finally {
            window.jQuery = jQueryOriginal;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
console.log("before:" +window.jQuery.fn.jquery);
var rgJQuery = unwindJquery(window.jQuery);
for (var ix in rgJQuery) { //listed in reverse order
    console.log(ix+"> "+rgJQuery[ix].fn.jquery);
}
console.log("after:" +window.jQuery.fn.jquery);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to see if its loaded with

```
if (typeof jQuery.ui != 'undefined') {
  // UI loaded
}
```

but having multiple jquery's loaded can bring trouble.